# Linkedin Company Search API : Get All Counts

Tags: python, linkedin-api

I need to get Employee Size Range for as many listed companies on Linkedin. I used Python, got the LinkedIn APIs.

However, the query only returns top 10 counts. How do you get the query to return all listed Counts ?

```
application = linkedin.LinkedInApplication(authentication)
application.search_company(selectors=[{'companies': ['name', 'employee-count-range']}])
```

Results: Only 10 Companies get listed in Output. How to get all the companies?

Comment: hard to tell without seeing more of the code and the response from the  api endpoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [LinkedIn API Documentation](https://developers.linkedin.com/documents/company-search)

> count: The number of jobs to return. Values can range between 0 and
>   110. The default value is 10. The total results available to any user depends on their account level.

And according to [Python LinkedIn Documentation](http://ozgur.github.io/python-linkedin/) example (although, this is not a `search_company`, but `search_job` method, this solution should also work for `search_company`):

```
application.search_job(selectors=[{'jobs': ['id',
                                            'customer-job-code',
                                            'posting-date']}],
                       params={'title': 'python', 'count': 2})
# Output
{u'jobs': {u'_count': 2,
  u'_start': 0,
  u'_total': 206747,
  u'values': [{u'customerJobCode': u'0006YT23WQ',
    u'id': 5174636,
    u'postingDate': {u'day': 21, u'month': 3, u'year': 2013}},
   {u'customerJobCode': u'00023CCVC2',
    u'id': 5174634,
    u'postingDate': {u'day': 21, u'month': 3, u'year': 2013}}]}}
```

You should pass `params` dictionary with `count` key.